# rails "undefined method" error inside loop which is not evaluated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

This code works properly (using HAML):

```
#comments
  - @blog.comments.each do |comment|
    .comment
      .username
        - if !eval("comment.user").nil?
          #{comment.user.email}
      .content
        #{comment.content}
```

However, if I remove the "eval" line i.e.

```
#comments
  - @blog.comments.each do |comment|
    .comment
      .username
        #{comment.user.email}
      .content
        #{comment.content}
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

**Even when there are no comments in the database** (hence the loop contents should not be evaluated). What is going on?

Comment: `- if !eval("comment.user").nil?` this is ugly, just use `- if comment.user`

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin thx, I was looking for some cleaner syntax. I thought I tried that before, but it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, problem solved!

Issue was that above the posted code, I had the line:

```
= form_for @blog.comments.build, :remote => true do |f|
```

When I moved that form below the loop the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
#comments
  - @blog.comments.each do |comment|
    .comment
      .username
        - if comment.user
          = comment.user.email
      .content
        = comment.content
```

I think the problem is that you are forcing ruby to evaluate comment.user.email with #{comment.user.email}.

Try this in the console:

```
def fail(param)
  if param
    puts "hello #{1/0}"
  end
end

fail(nil)
```

It will fail because of a division by 0, but param is nil.

Comment: The OP is asking why he's getting the nil.email bug whereas @blog.comments should be empty, since the comments table is empty in his DB (or so he says ;))

Comment: thx, but I believe I've had this issue in ERB templates too (without using ${} syntax)